# PyMongo gives client with wrong user creds?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a DB named `test` in my Mongo. I created a user inside `test` using below command.

```
db.createUser( 
  { 
    user: "user1", 
    pwd: "abc123", 
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" } ] 
  } 
)
```

but when I try to use the below connection URI, I am able to get the client

```
my_client = MongoClient("mongodb://user1:abc123@127.0.0.1:27017/admin")
```

My questions are

1. How can a user inside `test` DB can authenticate `admin` DB and give client?
2. Also using that client, I am not able to read or write into `test` DB?

Answer (score 1):

Users are authenticated against the database supplied in the `authSource` parameter. This defaults to `admin` (unless you have set a `defaultauthdb`), so in your case it will authenticate against the `admin` database, not `test`.

To authenticate against the `test` database, use:

```
mongodb://user1:abc123@127.0.0.1:27017/admin?authSource=test
```

Further reading:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/

Comment: But, how can admin db get authenticated, if I provide the user details of test db.

Comment: You probably created a user in admin previously. run a `db.getUsers()`

Comment: No, I have created user inside test db. But inside admin db when I give db.system.users.find(), I am able to find that user.